# using php form multiple select in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to query using the results of a search form. One of the fields I have is "state". I would like the user to be able to select multiple states and then get a list of results reflecting all the states selected. This is the code I have used for a single select form element for state. It reflects selecting all records if no selection is made for state, as well as sex, sale and salename:

```
$query  = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(saledate,'%m/%d/%Y') as saledatex FROM sdusa WHERE";


if (!empty($state)){ 
$query .= " state = '$state' AND";
}

if (!empty($sex)){ 
$query .= " sex = '$sex' AND";
}

if (!empty($sale)){ 
$query .= " breeder = '$sale' AND";
}

if (!empty($salename)){ 
$query .= " salename LIKE '%$salename%' AND";
}

$query .= " saledate >= $salestart
AND saledate <= $saleend
AND birthdate >= $birthstart
AND birthdate <= $birthend
AND actbw <= $actbw1 
AND adj205ww >= $adj205ww1
AND adj365yw >= $adj365yw1
AND rea >= $rea1
AND imf >= $imf1
AND sc >= $sc1

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
```

How would I adjust the query to get results from a multiple select list for state that would give me a list of results that reflects all states selected? I think I need to add a "foreach" statement possibly or a counter - but since I am newer to php am not real sure of the code.

Current output looks like this:

```
 <table align='center' width='780' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'     bordercolor='#000000'>
 <tr>
<td width='55' class='s11'><div align='center'>Reg #</div></td>
<td width='100' class='s11'><div align='center'>Name</div></td>  
 <td width='135' class='s11'><div align='center'>Sire</div></td>
 <td width='125' class='s11'><div align='center'>MGS</div></td>
 <td width='180' class='s11'><div align='center'>Breeder</div></td>
 <td width='25' class='s11'><div align='center'>St</div></td>
 <td width='60' class='s11'><div align='center'>Sale Date</div></td>  
 <td width='25' class='s11'><div align='center'>BW</div></td>
 <td width='25' class='s11'><div align='center'>WW</div></td>
<td width='25' class='s11'><div align='center'>YW</div></td>
 <td width='25' class='s11'><div align='center'>M</div></td>
 </tr>
 <?php 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr height='20'>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'><a href='sdindselect.php?registration_num=". $row ['registration_num'] ."'>" . $row['registration_num'] . "</a> </div></td>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'>" . $row['name'] . " </div></td>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'>" . $row['sire'] . " </div></td>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'>" . $row['sire3'] . " </div></td>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'>" . $row['breeder'] . $row['salname'] ." </div></td>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'>" . $row['salestate'] . " </div></td>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'>" . $row['saledatex'] . " </div></td>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'>" . $row['bw'] . " </div></td>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'>" . $row['ww'] . " </div></td>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'>" . $row['yw'] . " </div></td>";
echo "<td class='s11'><div align='center'>" . $row['milk'] . " </div></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: on a side note why don't you put your `center` in the `s11` class, just think of all the bandwidth your save...

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED!
A multiple select list will pass its values as an array. What you'll need to do is something like this:

```
if (!empty($state))
{
  $query .= "("; // Encapsulate state values so they'll be resolve independently

  foreach($states as $term)
  {
    if($term !== '')
    {
      $query .= " state = '".trim($term)."' OR";
    }
  }
  $query .= ") AND";
}
```

Comment: Stack 101 has the right idea above, but I would suggest using OR instead of AND because no rows with a single state assigned will be in multiple states.

Comment: No problem. That's also why I suggested encapsulating this part of the query in parentheses. When you start mixing AND statements with OR statements, the results are often hard to predict unless you separate them this way.

Comment: You'll have a trailing `OR` at the end... Which will fire a mysql error

Comment: Getting a query failed message - using `code'$query  = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(saledate,'%m/%d/%Y') as saledatex FROM sdusa WHERE";

$states = array();
$states = explode(" ",$state); 

if (!empty($state)){  
$query .= "("; 
// Encapsulate state values so they'll be resolve independently  
foreach($states as $term)  {
if($term !== '')    {      
$query .= " salestate = '".trim($term)."' OR";    }  }  
$query .= ") AND";} `code`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you :

```
if (!empty($state)){

$states = array();
```

Depending on how each `$state` value is sepertated in you query string

**Exemple :** `$state = "New Jersey,Wyoming,Oregon,Georgia,Maine,Arkansas"`

```
$states  = explode(",",$state); 
$first = true;

foreach($states as $term){

    if($term !== ''){

        if(!$first) $query .= " OR";

        $query .= " state = '".trim($term)."'";
        $first = false;

    }
}

$query .= " AND";

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Query is running, but no results - thank you for all you ideas - keep em coming!

Comment: What does your `$state` string look like, when you hav multiple values?

Comment: ack - i don't know - when I put: echo $state: it just says Array. Sorry I am such a newbie. Thanks for your patience

Comment: What does `printf($state);` give you?

Comment: It says Array. Sould I be declaring the $state variable - ie $state=$_POST['state'];

Comment: Well yes, I take it your posting your variables $state, $sex, $sale... from your search form? How were you getting them before?

Comment: SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(saledate,'%m/%d/%Y') as saledatex FROM sdusa WHERE salestate = 'Array' AND saledate >= 20110101 AND saledate <= 20130101 AND birthdate >= 20000101 AND birthdate <= 20130101 AND actbw <= 9999 AND adj205ww >= 0 AND adj365yw >= 0 AND rea >= -9999 AND imf >= -9999 AND sc >= -9999 AND ced <= 9999 AND bw <= 9999 AND ww >= -9999 AND yw >= -9999 AND radg >= -9999 AND yh <= 9999 AND scepd >= -9999 AND doc >= -9999 AND hp >= -9999 AND cem >= -9999 AND milk >= -9999 AND mkh >= -9999 AND mw >= -9999 AND mh >= -9999 AND en >= -9999

Comment: The result of selecting: <option value="" selected="selected">All States</option>

Comment: Do you have a link to a page I could look at? Also you need to use mysql_real_escape_string().